# Export Data with ClosedXML

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I know there are a lot of materials here about exporting data to Excel using ClosedXML but my situation is a bit unique.

I have a working code below that successfully exports data from GridView to excel file but my situation is unique in that when you run the code below, data is displayed on page load.

Our issue is we would rather not have the data displayed on the form.

All we would like to see is the Export to excel button only. Is this possible?

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Get Excel file" OnClick="ExportToExcel" runat="server" />

  Imports System
  Imports System.Collections.Generic
  Imports System.Configuration
  Imports System.Data
  Imports System.Data.SqlClient
  Imports System.Drawing
  Imports System.Globalization
  Imports System.IO
  Imports ClosedXML.Excel
  Imports System.Net.Mail
  Imports System.Linq
  Imports System.Net
  Imports System.Text
  Imports System.Threading
  Imports System.Web
  Imports System.Web.Configuration
  Imports System.Web.UI
  Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        BindData()
  End Sub

  Private Function GetData() As DataTable
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable")
                    Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                        cmd.Connection = con
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                        Using dt As New DataTable()
                            sda.Fill(dt)
                            Return dt
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub BindData()
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData()
        ViewState("Data") = dt
        Dim TotalRecords = Dt.Rows.Count()
        GridView1.DataSource = Dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ExportGridToExcel()
        Try
            Dim dt As DataTable = CType(ViewState("Data"), DataTable)
            dt.TableName = "Details"

            Using wb As XLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook()
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt)
                Response.Clear()
                Response.Buffer = True
                Response.Charset = ""
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=govt.xlsx")

                Using MyMemoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
                    Response.Flush()
                    dt.Dispose()
                    Response.[End]()
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Protected Sub ExportToExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ExportGridToExcel()
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
        ' Verifies that the control is rendered 
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is certainly no need to display or have that gridview.

So, say a button on the form when clicked exports the data.

So, then this:

```
Protected Sub cmdExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                                 ORDER BY HotelName")

    ExportToExcel(cmdSQL, "Hotels")

End Sub

Sub ExportToExcel(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, sTable As String)

    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmdSQL)
        dt.TableName = sTable
        Using wb As XLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook()
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt)
            Response.Clear()
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.Charset = ""
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={sTable}.xlsx")

            Using MyMemoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
                Response.Flush()
                dt.Dispose()
                Response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

Private Function GetData(cmd As SqlCommand) As DataTable
    Dim constr As String =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using (cmd)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return dt

End Function
```

So, note with above, you can set the "name" of the table and excel file that will be downloaded.

So, if you use say "MyHotels", then the excel file is given the name of MyHotels.xlsx.

Comment: You are as awesome as always. THANK YOUSO MUCH Albert, thank you